# Facebook Open Graph work on frontpage only

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have two Wordpress sites using YOAST SEO to generate Facebook Open Graph Meta Tag.All setting in both sites are same, but suddenly a site have an issue.
I've tried FB debugger to find out, Facebook Open Graph can only fetch data from my homepage,when I submit an article URL It says like this:
[Error parsing input URL, no data was cached, or no data was scraped.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBysA.png)

Additional, og:image not work entire my site.
I'm so confused, anyone can tell me how to fix it?

Comment: What URL do you have problem with?

Comment: All URL except home page, You can try with this http://bongdaquocte.vn/tay-ban-nha/copa-del-rey-granada-0-3-valencia-chien-thang-de-dang.html

Comment: This is was Facebook sees: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=http%3A%2F%2Fbongdaquocte.vn%2Ftay-ban-nha%2Fcopa-del-rey-granada-0-3-valencia-chien-thang-de-dang.html . So you need to debug why you don't send any data to Facebook

Comment: I found out the problem, when I change website URL to www. version, It works like a charm, but I prefer to use non-www version

Comment: Then figure out why your server is not sending any data to Facebook if you don't put www there

Comment: I can't find the exactly reason, I have tried to change other database link to my domain, but nothing changes. Facebook can only scrape my homepage :(